# What is the definitive evidence we have that quantum theory's probabilistic nature is physical and not epistemic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, measurement-problem, determinism

For example does superposition or wavefunction really occur in the physical quantum world or is it only a property of the quantum theory's framework and formalism to help us to make accurate predictions of actual results?

Since there is no consensus yet and a definitive explanation on the "measurement problem" can it be that the QT probabilistic nature is epistemic and not physical (i.e. real)?

Can it be that the probabilistic nature of the quantum to be an apparent effect?
(i.e. Most of the theories regarded as complete theories within their own context like Newtonian Mechanics or SR and GR are all talking and make distinction between actual phenomena and apparent phenomena. SR is full of these examples as well as GR which describes the "force of gravity" as an apparent effect due the curvature of spacetime. Even Newtonian-mechanics talks about fictitious forces like the centrifugal. As far as I know, I'm not aware about similarly quantum theories describing any apparent quantum phenomena? Why is that? Seems to me that the word "apparent" does not belong to the quantum vocabulary. Are there no apparent phenomena in the quantum world?).

As we refine more and more our methods and apparatus can it be that in the future quantum world could be described physically by thermodynamics and a type of quantum statistical mechanics and all this present "quantum weirdness" to be resolved by classical reasoning?

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between a $\psi$-epistemic ontological model and a $\psi$-ontic model of quantum mechanics, exactly?](/q/290522), and links therein, might prove informative.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think I know how to make this question more on-topic.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D9HkoHScdY some of the greatest minds in physics today express their skepticism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no opinion about whether the wavefunction is "real" or "just a trick." I have never even understood what the debate is about, since you could have the same argument about any mathematical object (eg an electric field vector).

There is a genuine physics question, however, in asking whether quantum mechanics is a **complete** formalism, or if there are additional ["hidden variables"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory) we don't observe. Perhaps our statistical interpretation of quantum mechanics is simply a coarse way of describing the behavior of these hidden variables, but if we could only find them we would see that physics really was deterministic after all.

Then the typical response is to point out that experimental demonstration of [Bell's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test) rule out that quantum mechanics can be explained by a theory where the "hidden variables" interact locally in a deterministic way.

At this stage, you can either accept that quantum mechanics is the simplest and best explanation of the data, or you can push into increasingly tiny loopholes in the experimental tests to find room for something other than quantum mechanics to explain what we have observed. There is a huge literature that has a cat-and-mouse type feel, with loopholes being proposed, and experiments closing the loopholes.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer and also bringing up the subject of "hidden variables" which was disproved by Bell's inequalities experiment. However, I never understood what the difference is between "hidden variables" and the intrinsic properties of elementary particles? It is my understanding that in the case of the intrinsic properties, these are fixed stable values, parameters, that can be measured but the mechanics of how these came to be is unknown.

Comment: @Markoul11 Well, for one thing, intrinsic properties of elementary particles like mass and charge are not hidden since we can measure them :) More seriously, the "hidden variables" idea is that quantum mechanics is only an approximation to the true theory. In the true theory, we would find that physics really is deterministic, not probabilistic. Quantum mechanics only *appeared* to be probabilistic because we didn't have all the information (kind of like thermodynamics). But this idea doesn't really work. Also I should clarify Bell's inequalities only disprove *local* hidden variables.

Comment: If assuming the "hidden variables" refer exactly to these physical mechanics and procedures which generate the specific values of these intrinsic properties of the particles, I find it very peculiar how a change of the spin of an entangled particle is not affected by these hidden mechanics? Maybe the hidden variables are entangled too?

Comment: @Markoul11 According to quantum mechanics, there are no hidden variables. Quantum mechanics is all you need to understand the behavior of entangled spins. Personally, given what we know experimentally and theoretically, I think it is overwhelmingly likely that quantum mechanics is a correct and complete description of Nature.

Comment: G. 't Hooft is a user on this site, and he is working on trying to find a deterministic theory , and has had discussions on this site on this subject

Comment: @annav Yes, it's good very smart people are around who don't simply accept the status quo and try to challenge it. It may be that I am just not smart and bold enough to see how to make progress in this direction.

Comment: @Markoul11 the Bell's inequalities haven't quite "disproved" the hidden variables: they only forbid _local_ hidden variables. For nonlocal ones there's e.g. [de Broglie–Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory), which reproduces the predictions of QM, but also predicts (unobservable) trajectories.

Comment: @Ruslan Which means that the fact remains that our physical world actually has non-local parts. It doesn't matter whether those non-local parts are observable or hidden variables, the non-locality is the fact that we need to digest. It's precisely this non-locality which makes quantum mechanical effects like entanglement so counterintuitive (and cool, and powerful...). That is the key take-away from the Bell test, imho.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica that's a matter of interpretation. The fact that a theory contains these non-local objects doesn't automatically make them belong to the physical world. Some people are more comfortable with non-realism, others with non-locality. You just seem to be of the latter type.

Comment: @Ruslan Isn't it a bit hard to do physics when you opt for non-realism? I'd have thought that physicists mostly accept the non-locality, even though grudgingly.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica no, it's not hard at all. For one, you have a local wavefunction (not the Schrödinger's one, but e.g. the solutions of Dirac equation, Maxwell's equations). From this we can calculate all the measurable quantities without actually thinking about interpretations (AKA "shut up and calculate"). Physics doesn't really depend on the interpretation: all the interpretations either have to be consistent with the core theory (QM/QFT), or else they have testable predictions that diverge from it and are potential discoveries.

Answer (score 1):

On your first question - whether wavefunctions and superposition are 'real' or 'a model making accurate predictions' - there is no way to tell. This is metaphysics. Since by definition there is no observable difference between true and false models so long as they both make accurate predictions, there is no scientific way to distinguish them.

On your second question - whether the probabilistic nature of the Copenhagen interpretation (wavefunction collapse to an eigenstate of the observation) could be only 'apparent' - the answer is 'yes'. The Everett interpretation (also misleadingly known as the 'many-worlds' interpretation) is deterministic, local, complete, time-reversible, and realist. There is no randomness, no spooky faster-than-light action-at-a-distance, no unexplained irreversible 'wavefunction collapse' process triggered by some special vaguely defined property of *observation*.

Quantum superpositions and wavefunctions apply at the sub-atomic level, and both sides of the debate accept that. The Everett interpretation adds no new physics to this, it simply points out that the quantum theory predicts that we will see at the macroscopic level exactly what we *do* see - i.e. a quantum universe appears classical to quantum observers inside it.

The principle by which this works can also be seen in classical physics, in the case of 'normal modes of vibration' of coupled oscillators. Here, two independent oscillators can be jointly represented with a matrix equation $\mathbf{\ddot{x}}=M\mathbf{x}$ where the matrix $M$ is block-diagonal. (Compare with the Klein-Gordon equation in quantum mechanics.) When a weak coupling is introduced between the oscillators, by setting some of the off-diagonal terms non-zero, the two oscillators enter a superposition of synchronised states, which are related to the eigenvectors of the modified matrix. The eigenvectors are orthogonal to one another, meaning they oscillate independently. This is how the Everett interpretation says an observation works. The two independent oscillators are the observer and the observed. The weak interaction between them is the process of observation. The synchronisation of oscillations in each normal mode is the observer state becoming correlated with the observed state (i.e. acquiring information about it). The orthogonality of the normal modes is why each observer state can perceive none of the others. If the observer is a quantum oscillator, weakly interacting, then it will enter a superposition of states, each of them corresponding to only one possible outcome, each of which behaves completely independently of the others, as if none of the others exists. It is 'as if there were separate universes, in each of which one of the possible outcomes occurs, all existing simultaneously' (hence the name 'Many Worlds').

Everett's [original thesis](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/manyworlds/pdf/dissertation.pdf) is well worth reading. There are lots of misunderstandings and distorted versions floating around. There remain some genuine philosophical problems about it, but the same is true of all the others, and it is deterministic, local, complete, time-reversible, and realistic, which should all count in its favour. And in this interpretation, the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics is only apparent, so it is at least possible.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive insightful answer. Strangely enough I have currently a paper under preparation that exploits these orthogonal oscillations you are referring but they are not independent. It is a deterministic 4-dimensional string spinor  emulating the free electron at rest in an unknot 1/2 spin dynamic topology manifold. The string relativistically revolves vertically and at the same time spins horizontally.  As for the "... 'real' or 'a model making accurate predictions' - there is no way to tell. This is metaphysics." I don't agree. It is called, beyond the SM physics.